# (iOS Swift) plist work on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsmutablearray, plist

This plist work correctly on simulator...read and write plist data without problems!Work correctly also deleting data. It don't crash!!
If instead launch the app on device don't read nothing data!
I am using Swift 3 version 8.3.2.

Any idea?

thanks in advance!

read plist

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory:AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
        let path = documentsDirectory.appending("orari_marcate.plist")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let fileExists:Bool = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)
        let lista_marcate : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        var marcate2 = NSMutableArray()


        if fileExists == false {

            marcate2 = NSMutableArray()

        } else  {

            marcate2 = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)!

        }
```

write plist

```
  lista_marcate.setValue(risultato_Ora.text, forKey: "fine_Ora")
            lista_marcate.setValue(risultato_Min.text, forKey: "fine_Min")


            marcate2.add(lista_marcate)

            marcate2.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
```